# Is there any Higher order function which can iterate through a array of objects and return true or false

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary, iterator

(except foreach,map,reduce,filter, for, while and do while)
(return true(if no object with attribute read : false found) or false(if any one of the objects contains property read : false).)
Consider the following array:

```
let allRead = true;
let notifications = [
{message: ‘Lorem’, read: true},
{message: ‘Ipsum’, read: true},
{message: ‘Dolor’, read: true},
{message: ‘Sit’, read: false},
{message: ‘Amet’, read: true}
];
```

You have to set the allRead variable to false using a built-in higher-order function on the
notifications array. Conditions: a) You cannot use for, while, do-while loops b) You cannot use
forEach(), map(), reduce(), filter().

So far I have used some and find. I am pretty sure its not find because find always returns the whole object. you cannot return other thing than what you iterate.

```
allRead = notifications.find((obj) => {
    console.log("yes");
   if (obj.read === false) {
     console.log(obj.read);
     return obj;
   }
});
console.log(allRead);
```

on the other hand , using some has been a partial success...but it returns true when read : false found but what i want is that if read: false found then set the allRead to false, regardless of other iterations.

```
allRead = notifications.some((not) => not.read !== true);
console.log(allRead);
```

I have also noticed that if I use a if else condition or switch case statement and return true, false based on condition...then when it returns true it autometically breaks and avoids the other iteraions.

```
allRead = notifications.some((not) => {
  switch (not.read) {
     case false:
       break;
       return false;
     default:
      return true;
    }
 });
console.log(allRead);
```

Comment: You're looking for either `some` or `every`.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all elements in an array match a given condition.

```
const allRead = notifications.every(({read})=>read);
```

You can also use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) by simply negating the result to check if there was no element that matched the condition.

```
const allRead = !notifications.some(({read})=>!read);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check all values in a array list (in this case array of objects) needs to pass certain condition to return true if not false, array.every can be used.
Need more info or example, if this not what you are looking for..

Ref MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every